# Get top x clips by language in the new Twitch api by country

Tags: twitch, twitch-api

So I want to get top x clips from twitch per country, I've noticed that there is an endpoint for this:
https://dev.twitch.tv/docs/v5/reference/clips#get-top-clips
However, that is an old deprecated API and I cannot find an endpoint for this in the new API. Am I blind? Or is it not there? If it isn't, is it safe to use the old API? How long will I be able to use it?

Comment: `#get-top-clips` got replaced with [#get-clips](https://dev.twitch.tv/docs/api/reference#get-clips) as shown on [the migration guide](https://dev.twitch.tv/docs/api/migration#endpoint-equivalence) and just selecting on the language doesn't seem to be possible anymore, it must have a game-id, with that you can then filter on language. but that does seem a bit inefficient

Comment: Well that sucks, do you have any idea how long will I be able to use the old API?

Comment: the only information i could find about the v5 shutdown date is [this](https://discuss.dev.twitch.tv/t/confused-about-twitch-apis/24050/5) and therefor i think helix is still getting more features and a shutdown date has not been released yet(but i might be wrong). and once a shutdown date is released expect atleased a month time before its offline